# Elasticsearch aggregations: Always return a field in term aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

All my users have a city associated with them and i am doing aggregation on it. I always want `Unspecified` field to be returned from aggregation response to get the users who have not entered their cities. Is there a way I can always get `Unspecified` in result irrespective of whether its count is in top 10 or not. Since the no of cities is very big i don't want to query all of them just to obtain count of `Unspecified`.

Data schema is:

```
"mappings": {
     "users": {
        "dynamic": "false",
        "_all": {
           "enabled": false
        },
        "properties": {
           "city": {
              "properties": {
                 "geopoint": {
                    "type": "geo_point"
                 },
                 "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                 }
              }
           },
           "id": {
              "type": "integer"
           }
       ...}
```

Aggregation i am doing is:

```
{
  "aggs" : {
    "cities" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "city.name" }
    }
  }
}
```

I have some other queries and filters. This aggregation works fine. I get list of top ten cities but I also was the count of `Unspecified`

Expected results is:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "cities" : {
        "buckets" : [ 
            {
                "key" : "New York",
                "doc_count" : 120
            },
            {
                "key" : "Chicago",
                "doc_count" : 50
            },
             .
             .
             .
            {
                "key" : "Unspecified",
                "doc_count" : 4
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a few sample documents and the expected aggregation result you'd like?

Comment: You can filter your data with https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-exists-query.html not exists query, then aggregate them.

Comment: @Val i have added data mapping and expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage the [missing value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_missing_value_12) settings of the `terms` aggregation. You simply specify the key of the bucket that will collect all documents that don't have any term in the specified field:

```
{
  "aggs" : {
    "cities" : {
        "terms" : { 
           "field" : "city.name",
           "missing": "Unspecified"                 <--- add this
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Val. Adding missing always returns it in response irrespective of whether it is in top 10 or not. Didn't knew that. Thanks again.